# Error Showing as Class Cast Exception while changing the value of combobox in Javafx

Tags: javafx

On selection of Tableview row, it display the data in the combobox, 
i try to display the value in the comboxbox from tableview using this code.

```
private void showInputDetails(InputConfigurationModel ipmodel) {

        if (ipmodel != null) {
            cmbfiletype.setValue(ipmodel.getFiletype().toString());           
    }
```

My **Inputconfiguartion Model** class:

```
public class InputConfigurationModel {

        public StringProperty filetype = new SimpleStringProperty();    
        public InputConfigurationModel(String filetype) {

            this.filetype = new SimpleStringProperty(filetype);
        }

        public InputConfigurationModel() {
        }

        public String getFiletype() {
            return filetype.get();
        }

        public void setFiletype(String value) {
            filetype.set(value);
        }

        public StringProperty filetypeProperty()
        {
            return filetype;
        }

    //    @Override
    //    public String toString() {
    //        return filetype.toString(); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    //    }                       
    }
```

but if i try change the value of combobox for update it display error as 
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to Clover.Converter.Model.ExtensionModel

i am trying to change the value in the combobox from this code

Loading the combobox value from this **Loadfile** method

```
    public void LoadFile() {

    try {

    String sql = "select * from EXTENSION";
    PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
    rs = ps.executeQuery(sql);
    while (rs.next()) {
    ExtensionModel extModel = new ExtensionModel();
    filetypelstupdate_ip = FXCollections.observableArrayList(extModel);
    String ext_type = rs.getString("EXT_TYPE");
    String ext_name = rs.getString("EXT_NAME");
    int ext_id=Integer.parseInt(rs.getString("EXT_ID"));
    extModel.setExttype(ext_type);
    extModel.setExtname(ext_name);
    extModel.setExtid(ext_id);
    cmbfiletype.getItems().addAll(filetypelstupdate_ip); 

        cmbfiletype.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<ExtensionModel>() {
        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends ExtensionModel> observable, ExtensionModel oldValue, ExtensionModel newValue) {                    
               aaa(newValue);   

        }
    });

    catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
   }

}
        public void aaa(ExtensionModel exm){

         if(cmbfiletype!=null)
        {       
            txtextid.setText(exm.getExtid().toString());
            System.out.println("txtextid"+txtextid);
        }

    }
```

i dont how to solve this error? tried everything but still coming class cast exception

my error is coming in **LoadFile** Method in this code first line

```
**cmbfiletype.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<ExtensionModel>() {**
        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends ExtensionModel> observable, ExtensionModel oldValue, ExtensionModel newValue) {

            aaa(newValue);           

    });

    }
    } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
   }
```

First it display the value in the comboxbox from the tableview which is a string in **INPUTCONFIGURATION** model class and thn i tried to change the  the combobox value which comes from LoadFile method, hence it comes as class cast exception. kindly help me how to solve this class cast exception error.

Comment: Just don't use raw types, unless it's absolutely necessary. I'm pretty sure the compiler would have complained, it the type parameters were properly specified...

Comment: It is necessary to add raw data here.. coz i want to update my combobox "cmbfiletype" value when it needed which come from ExtensionModel . is there any way i can avoid this error?

Comment: i heard the solution  about StringConverter .. but not getting a idea where to use that "StringConverter" in my code?